# Cannot use Firebase Client SDK `firebase.auth()` under Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not able to use `firebase.auth()` in Client SDK under Node.js.
I'm using Node.js `9.11.2` and Firebase `4.13.1`.

I looked at the documentation, and it specifically has a Client SDK section for Node.js with `auth` namespace. So I'm very confused that `firebase.auth` is not defined.

Have I done anything wrong?

```
$ node
> const firebase = require('firebase/app')
undefined
> firebase
{ __esModule: true,
  initializeApp: [Function: initializeApp],
  app: { [Function: app] App: [Function: FirebaseAppImpl] },
  apps: [Getter],
  Promise: [Function: Promise],
  SDK_VERSION: '4.13.0',
  INTERNAL:
   { registerService: [Function: registerService],
     createFirebaseNamespace: [Function: createFirebaseNamespace],
     extendNamespace: [Function: extendNamespace],
     createSubscribe: [Function: createSubscribe],
     ErrorFactory: [Function: ErrorFactory],
     removeApp: [Function: removeApp],
     factories: {},
     useAsService: [Function: useAsService],
     Promise: [Function: Promise],
     deepExtend: [Function: deepExtend] },
  default: [Circular] }
> require('firebase/auth')
{}
> firebase
{ __esModule: true,
  initializeApp: [Function: initializeApp],
  app: { [Function: app] App: [Function: FirebaseAppImpl] },
  apps: [Getter],
  Promise: [Function: Promise],
  SDK_VERSION: '4.13.0',
  INTERNAL:
   { registerService: [Function: registerService],
     createFirebaseNamespace: [Function: createFirebaseNamespace],
     extendNamespace: [Function: extendNamespace],
     createSubscribe: [Function: createSubscribe],
     ErrorFactory: [Function: ErrorFactory],
     removeApp: [Function: removeApp],
     factories: {},
     useAsService: [Function: useAsService],
     Promise: [Function: Promise],
     deepExtend: [Function: deepExtend] },
  default: [Circular] }
> .exit
```

P.S. `require('firebase')` shows similar result.

Update: I'm able to get this to work with `4.11.0` and `4.12.1`, looking through the release notes now. But any help is hugely appreciated.

Update: Both `4.13.x` and `5.x.x` series don't work.

Comment: Please explain what exactly about the output you found confusing.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry about that...

Comment: If some core functionality of a library no longer works after incrementing a non-major version number of a library, that sounds like a bug.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/